# Stream Flush vs FlushAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Apart from the [Flush()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138277%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, I noticed that the [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Stream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class also has a [FlushAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.flush.aspx) method. In what situations would you use the [FlushAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.flush.aspx) method? Is flushing a buffer so expensive as to warrant running it asynchronously?

Comment: Yes, it can be very expansive because it'll actually write data to underlying media. You can have a lot of data to write or media may be pretty slow (network, for example) or there may be layers of abstractions in the middle that will do further processing before effective writing. It can be as much expansive as any other writing operation.

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: OK, I did it (I tried to expand it little bit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can be very expensive because it *may* actually write data to underlying media.

Any of these conditions may be true:

- You have a lot of data to write (according to buffer size).
- Media itself may be pretty slow (network or a device with a slow interface).
- There may be layers of abstractions in the middle that will do further processing before effective writing (a compression/encryption abstraction for example).

It can be **expensive as much as any other writing operation** then there is `Async` version (moreover it'll help API consistency).

How `FlushAsync()` is implemented is...an implementation detail, it may be a simple `Task` in thread pool or something more complex (asynchronous I/O may involve OS itself). It may even be synchronous (imagine to flush a `MemoryStream`, it has not any buffer).

Comment: on the "a lot of data", note this includes all other pending IOs, not just those that originated from the use of the stream. This is why it is best practice to not call FlushAsync().

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather, calling `stream.Write()` may or may not put data in an intermediate in-memory buffer before being offloaded to its target destination. When this happens, `stream.Write()` unblocks before all of the data has actually been written.

The role of `stream.Flush()` would be to block the program until the intermediate buffer is clear. Depending on transfer speed and size of the data, you may want to `Flush()` asynchronously.